# sql_range_query error with Sphinx

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

While setting up Sphinx on my production server, this strange error came up when trying to index

```
ERROR: index 'benefit_core': sql_range_query: You have an error in your SQL 
syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

This doesn't happen on my local machine. And yes, that is an empty string.

Does anyone seen this type of issue before?

**benefit.rb**

```
define_index do 
  # Fields
  indexes category
  indexes title
  indexes tags
  indexes description
  indexes brief_description
  indexes brand
  indexes short_description
  indexes long_description
  indexes benefit_description
  indexes address.city
  indexes address.state
  indexes address.street_1
  where sanitize_sql(["active = true and expiration > ?", Time.now]) 
  set_property :field_weights => {
    :title => 15,
    :tags => 10,
    :brand => 10,
    :description => 3
  }
end
```

Thinking-Sphinx - 1.4.4

Sphinx - 0.9.9

Thank you!

Comment: Please post your query and your define_index block from your model.

Comment: @Dex I added the model's define_index. There error happens durring indexing, so I don't even get a chance to test a query.

Comment: When do you see the error? Did you run `rake ts:config` and `rake ts:rebuild`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being with the `sanitize_sql` method.  I replaced that line with:

```
where "active = true AND expiration > \"#{Time.now.to_formatted_s(:db)}\""
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are running the most recent version of Thinking Sphinx, 3.0.4 or so. Looks like there has been some issues with `sanitize_sql`

https://github.com/freelancing-god/thinking-sphinx/issues/213

Also try re-writing the line to be

```
where sanitize_sql(["active = ? and expiration > ?", true, Time.now])
```

Also try commenting out all the lines and gradually add them back to determine exactly where the error is occurring.